# cocos2d-x- set draw() method interval

Tags: cocos2d-x

What is the default interval of draw method call in cocos2dx engine? Can we set it manually? I couldn't find much information about it online. After researching a bit I found that update() method interval step could be adjusted by setting setAnimationInterval. Can I set a specific interval for draw method too?

Answer (score 0):

In cocos2d, draw method is responsible for drawing each and everything you see on screen so it is called at frame rate to refresh the screen. In other words, you can set the interval of draw method by setting frame rate of your cocos2d engine using `setAnimationInterval`.